# Lit playground downloaded code don't run locally

Tags: lit

I downloaded my-timer files from Lit playground (https://lit.dev/playground/#sample=docs/what-is-lit)
what I found when I unzip the folder:

1. my-timer.ts
2. icons.ts
3. index.html
4. package.json

downloaded package.json contains below dependencies:

`{ "dependencies": { "lit": "^2.0.0", "@lit/reactive-element": "^1.0.0", "lit-element": "^3.0.0", "lit-html": "^2.0.0" } }`

I removed the above package.json and added another package.json file suggested by (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/the-lit-path#1) VS Code setup section.

here is my new package.json file (https://gist.github.com/e111077/c9d4512dcc35f483abbebf95da24609b)

also added tsconfig.json file as I am getting errors for typescript.
and also added web-dev-server as suggested.
after doing all the above step I run the below command npm run serve, but nothing is on http://localhost:8000/
I don't know what am I missing?

my latest code is here (https://github.com/abhijeet-shelhalkar/my-timer-lit).
please guide me through the right steps.
and what is wrong in my code?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: @brc-dd No error, just blank screen and in devTools console NO specific error

Comment: Your typescript code is not compiling. You need to run `tsc --watch` and that serve command concurrently.

Comment: @brc-dd: Thanks, Now I can see the timers but timer are not updating when I click on play button & when I put debugger in DevTools they stop at proper functions but the timer is not updating / resetting.

Comment: In tsconfig.json by adding `useDefineForClassFields": false` for the @property decorator to work. 
timers are working now.